# Getting error 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' while creating blank listbox in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create a listbox which should be blank initially. But I getting error

> > System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is no ViewData item of type >>'IEnumerable' that has the key 'rightSelectednumbers'.'

I have not written any controller code for this. Initially, I just want to create it. Anyone please guide me where I am going wrong?

Class

```
public class NumberClass
   {
       public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> rightnumbers { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<int> rightSelectednumbers { get; set; }
   }
```

View

Please have a look View

```
   {
  <div class="col-md-6" style="font-family:Arial">
          @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.rightSelectednumbers, Model.rightnumbers, new { @class = "listBox" })
     <input type="submit" value="move right" />   
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="font-family:Arial">
      @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.rightnumbers, new SelectList(Model.rightnumbers, "Value", "Text", Model.rightSelectednumbers), new { @class = "listBox" })
 <input type="submit" value="move right"/>
```

Comment: When I tried your code, I am getting `System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items'` error.

Comment: Please make sure you populate the model collection (model.rightNumbers) before returing the View(model) in Controller/Action.